# How to reuse iMessage's photo picker in our own apps?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

There is a new photo picker menu in iMessage (iOS 8):[image]

Is it possible to reuse that component? Is there an API for it?

Comment: It's `UIActionController` combined with `UIImagePickerController`.

Comment: @rmaddy As far as I understand, `UIImagePickerController` can only be used as a fullscreen view. How can I tell it to show photos in the small view shown in the picture? Do you have any code examples or hints to a specific API method?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. There is no standard component that shows the recent photo library pictures above the action sheet.

Answer (score 5):

Check this out: BRNImagePickerSheet

https://github.com/larcus94/BRNImagePickerSheet